# Python int to percent

Tags: python, range, percentage

I need monthlyPayment as percentage so instead of range = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
I need range = [0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08]

Do you know how to do it, and still get the calculation from totalPayment

```
import math 

loanAmt=int(input("Enter the Amount (greater then 0) of the Loan: "))

numYears=int(input("Enter the number of years as an integer: "))

for monthlyRate in range(4,9):

   monthlyPayment = loanAmt * monthlyRate / (1 - math.pow(1 / (1 + monthlyRate), numYears * 12))

   totalPayment = monthlyPayment * numYears * 12
   print("{0:.0f}%".format(monthlyRate),'\t','$%.2f' %monthlyPayment,'\t','\t','$%.2f' %totalPayment)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
for monthlyRate in (x/100.0 for x in range(4,9)):
    print monthlyRate

0.04
0.05
0.06
0.07
0.08
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Anyway my result is still off by a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
percent_rate = [rate/100.0 for rate in monthly_rate]
# where monthly_rate is the list of all ints like [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: this can be used too, thanks

Comment: @Rujke what I didn't realize is that Alex's answer also uses List Comprehensions in one way, adrenaline is what forced me to give this answer at that moment.